# Equilibrium and centripetal acceleration

Tags: rotational-dynamics, equilibrium

Why is there still a non zero centripetal acceleration for a particle at equilibrium in uniform circular motion if equilibrium implies total Force = 0?

Comment: Since Sum of forces acting on my material point includes the say Normal force which is my centripetal acceleration force here. But if the sum of all external forces on my point = 0 then why doesn't N = 0 (if it does then I am no longer rotating)

Comment: If the particle is accelerating, it is not at equilibrium.

Comment: Circular motion does not imply Force = Zero.  Suggest you consider reading up on [uniform circular motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Have look at this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304679/tangential-acceleration-for-uniform-circular-motion/304702#304702 . Change in direction means **accleration**, hence **force**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A particle in uniform circular motion is not in equilibrium by definition. As you noted there is a non zero centripetal force. For a object to be in equilibrium, the sum of the forces acting on it must be zero (that is the definition of equilibrium).

Answer (score -1):

Centripetal force can be cancelled by centrifuge force so net acceleration may be zero and body can be in equilibrium