# While determining phase, is it okay to choose displacement as zero?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

There was this sentence in my book on simple harmonic motion, under the section where they explained it in terms of uniform circular motion.

> The projection on X axis of a particle p as well as it's Y axis can be indicated by cosine and sine functions of time respectively. They'll have the same amplitude, but is found to differ by a phase of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Does that mean when the particle is in equilibrium it's phase is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (X axis projection). I deduced it from the following steps;

$$0 = \cos \phi \rightarrow \phi = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

There is little connection to equilibrium in your description (see, e.g., [Equilibrium and centripetal acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304964/equilibrium-and-centripetal-acceleration)).
The phase between the projection on the $x$- and the $y$-axes determines the type of the motion. From your description, you can write: $x\left(t\right)=r\cos\left(\omega t+\phi_x\right)$ and $y\left(t\right)=r\sin\left(\omega t+\phi_y \right)$. When the phase difference $\Delta \phi = \phi_y-\phi_x = 0$, the particle moves along a circle with radius $r$. You can see this by substituting $\omega t=0,\pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2$ and plot on an $x-y$ plane. When the phase difference is $\Delta\phi=\pi/2$, the motion is linear along a line crossing the $x$-axis at the origin with a slope of $\pi/4$ as in this case you get $x(t)=y(t)=r\cos\left(\omega t+\phi_x\right)$.